# Characteristics of radius of blood vessel

Tags: physiology

**Which properties do determine the radius of blood vessel?**

I have these thoughts

- distension,
- elasticity,
- contractility and
- cross-sectional area of the walls.

**Is there any other properties?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of a blood vessel is entirely defined by only two parameters:

1.blood pressure

2.compliance of the vessel walls

Of course, active contraction can decrease the vessel radius. Physically, this is a decrease in compliance, so the above relation always remains true.